# Добавление новых темплейтов в юзер контролл в зависимости от данных привязки

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Можно ли каким-то образом контролировать привязку из dependency object в юзерконтролле? Мне необходимо проверить наличие данных в привязке, и выбрать соответсвтующий юзерконтролл для вставки внутрь контролла, к которому привязываются эти данные. Что-то по типу

```
    if (args.NewValue != null) myUserControl.Content.Add(newMySecondControll())
```

вот как-то так

Comment: Пример кода на XAML можно?

Comment: да в том-то и дело, что нет подобного ещё. с подобным способом друг подсказал. 
сейчас делаю так: создал много маленьких контроллов (отдельно контролл для аудио контента, видео, фото, товаров и тд), использую у них атрибут x:DeferedLoadStrategy, в общем контролле собираю это в один контролл и привязываю общий объект джсона. Но мне кажется, что, как минимум, можно это все намного аккуратнее сделать.